# Customize the CSS classes passed to django form errors with custom `ErrorList`

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to utilize Bootstrap for my django project and therefore always pass a CSS class to every form error. Let's name it "custom_class".

I read the docs and it tells me that theoretically this setup should work:

```py
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList


class BootstrapErrorList(ErrorList):
    error_class = "custom_class"


class BaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_class = BootstrapErrorList


class FormA(forms.ModelForm, BaseForm):
    # ...
class FormB(forms.Form, BaseForm):
    # ...
```

There is no error or anything but also the "custom_class" does not show up in rendered html. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format) is where I informed myself. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75266460/18018869) unanswered "question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of tweaking I got it to work properly:

```py
class BootstrapErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __init__(self, initlist=None, error_class=None, renderer=None):
        error_class = "alert alert-danger"
        super().__init__(initlist=initlist, error_class=error_class, renderer=renderer)


class BaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_class = BootstrapErrorList

class FormA(forms.ModelForm, BaseForm):
    # ...
class FormB(forms.Form, BaseForm):
    # ...
```

This gives every form which is inheriting from `BaseForm` the css classes "alert" and "alert-danger".